# Go to a specific web page using "attr" binding

Tags: knockout.js, devextreme

Hi all I am doing a mobile application and I got a requirement like we need to go to a specific web page when we load the values, so as per sample I tried the following

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'gotoGoogle', title: 'gotoGoogle' } ">
    <div data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } ">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: url, title: details }">Google</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my javascript using `knockout` i have done the following

```
 var viewModel = {
    url: ko.observable("http://www.google.com"),
    details: ko.observable("Google"),
};

return viewModel;
```

[image]

But I am unable to open the page as per required so can some one help me

Comment: Your code should just work fine. So most likely devextreme is doing something here... have your checked your browser's console are there any errors? Have you checked the DOM during runtime how is it look like?

Comment: probably you have error, higher than attr binding applied

Comment: The answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634751/sandbox-access-violation-when-using-tinyeditor-wysiwyg-editor-in-chrome-extensio) may shed some light on your issue.